# How can I access to public properties/method of an object represented by $this->myObject in my class?

Tags: php, object, types, casting

I'm trying to access getters of a custom object. I wanted to send the object to the constructor params (I'm currently sending to the `build` method (but

My class representing an object that I'd like to display its values :

```
class User{ 
        private $id;
        private $name;
        private $email;  

     public function __construct(int $id, string $name, string $email) { 
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
     }

     public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
     }

     ... // the other getters
}
```

In my Page :

```
$myUser = new User(1, "toto", "toto@url.com");

$blockUser = new UserBlock($sqlConnection);
$blockUser->setUser($myUser);
$blockUser->build();
```

interface IBlock :

```
interface IBlock {
    function __construct($sqlConnection);
    function build();
}
```

UserBlock class:

```
class UserBlock implements IBlock {
    private $myUser;

    public function __construct($sqlConnection) {
       ...
    }

    public setUser($myUser) {
       $this->myUser = $myUser;
    }

    function build() {
       echo "Name = ".$this->myUser->getName(); // ERROR: Doesn't know the type of $this->myUser so can't access to getName method.

       $tempVarUser = $this->myUser;
       echo "Name = ".$tempVarUser->getName(); // ERROR: Doesn't know the type of $tempVarUser so can't access to getName method.
    }
}
```

With my code structure, how can I access to the properties and methods of the object User represented by the variable `$this->myUser` in the `UserBlock` class ?

I have to remove the implements of the Interface and send the `User` object to the `build` method as parameter (which is not allowing by my interface here).
Hope this is clear. Thanks for your help.